# Не могу понять почему реализовывается код по принципу паттерна "Монотонность"

Tags: python, ооп

Не могу понять, почему в аттрибут класса values я получаю аргументы сразу с 3 экземпляров.

```
class Vector:
    values = []
    
    def __init__ (self, *args):
        self.args = args
        for i in self.args:
            self.values.append(i)            
  
    def __str__ (self):
        if len(self.values) > 0:
            return str(self.values)
        else:
            return f"Vector is empty"

v1 = Vector (1, 11, 111)
v2 = Vector (2, 22, 222)
v3 = Vector (3, 33, 333, 3333)
print (v1)

В консоли получаем:
[1, 11, 111, 2, 22, 222, 3, 33, 333, 3333]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

потому что вы объявляете список values для всего класса, а не для экземпляра.
попробуйте так:

```
class Vector:
#    values = []
    
    def __init__ (self, *args):
        self.args = args
        self.values = []
        for i in self.args:
            self.values.append(i)            
  
    def __str__ (self):
        if len(self.values) > 0:
            return str(self.values)
        else:
            return f"Vector is empty"

v1 = Vector (1, 11, 111)
v2 = Vector (2, 22, 222)
v3 = Vector (3, 33, 333, 3333)
print(v1)
```

> [1, 11, 111]

Comment: Да, уже лучше, благодарю Вас!
Но разве в моей варианте, когда мы обращаемся через self к списку values, мы не добавляем в список только в определенном экземпляре? Объясните пожалуйста что куда и откуда идет

Comment: В вашем варианте при создании экземпляра ему передаётся values класса. Разумеется, вы добавляете в список значения только в определённом экземпляре, но поскольку список общий для класса, каждый экземпляр дописывает в него свои значения.

Comment: Можно даже не закомментаривать список в самом классе, будет всё-равно работать правильно, просто он перестанет использоваться )  Экземпляры просто получают автоматам свойства класса и если не разорвать эту связь явным присваиванием `self.values = []`, то все они используют один и тот же список.